# MPMoviePlayerViewController - sound Is heard, but no video is seen

Tags: xcode

The QuickTime player appears over my View Controller layer as it should and the video file "Happy" plays completely through, but no video shows. Only audio is heard. And after completion, the QuickTime player transitions back to previous View Controller as it should.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Happy" ofType:@"m4v"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController * playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];               
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
[playerController.moviePlayer play];
[playerController release];
playerController=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge we cannot play the m4v files.Convert it to mp4

Comment: Ah...iPhone 4.3 Simulator used to support that video format. I have even tried .mov, and it does not work. I was just able to get a .m4v file type to play successfully (both audio and video).

Comment: ...time to update my simulator version. Thanks for your answer